# AWS Lambda package deployment

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'm trying to deploy a python .zip package as an AWS Lambda

I choose the hello-python Footprint.

I created the 1st lambda with the inline code, after that I tried to change to upload from a development .zip.

The package I used is a .zip contains a single file called `hello_python.py` with the same code as the default inline code sample, which is shown below:

```
from __future__ import print_function

import json

print('Loading function')


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    #print("Received event: " + json.dumps(event, indent=2))
    print("value1 = " + event['key1'])
    print("value2 = " + event['key2'])
    print("value3 = " + event['key3'])
    return event['key1']  # Echo back the first key value
    #raise Exception('Something went wrong')
```

After I click "save and test", nothing happens, but I get this weird red ribbon, but no other substantive error messages. The logs and the run results do not exhibit any change if modifying to source, repackaging and uploading it again.[image]

Comment: Does anything appear in CloudWatch Logs?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Lambda functions requires a handler in the format `<FILE-NAME-NO-EXTENSION>.<FUNCTION-NAME>`. In your case the handler is set to `lambda_function.lambda_handler`, which is the default value assigned by AWS Lambda). However, you've named your file `hello_python.py`. Therefore, AWS Lambda is looking for a python file named `lambda_function.py` and finding nothing.

To fix this either:

1. Rename your `hello_python.py` file to `lambda_function.py`
2. Modify your lambda function handler to be `hello_python.lambda_handler`

You can see an example of how this works in the [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-programming-model-handler-types.html) where they create a python function called `my_handler()` inside the file `hello_python.py`, and they create a lambda function to call it with the handler `hello_python.my_handler`.